# adding a parameter to href link

Tags: html, asp.net, parameters, webforms, href

I need to send the user to another webpage but setting up parameters, I am using the QueryString in that page for that. This is my code:

```
<a href= "school_info.aspx?edit_school=true&school=" + SchoolId>School Profile</a>
```

SchoolId is a parameter that I need to add, I have tried `.ToString()` and it does not work, any help?

The parameter is defined in the aspx.cs code

Comment: could you show some code what you have done?

Comment: always post related code so that one can have clear understanding of your requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way,

```js
function func(){ 
 var SchoolId  = 0;
 window.location.href = "school_info.aspx?edit_school=true&school=" + SchoolId;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a onclick="func();">Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

That is, calling the href tag from the javascript after manipulating the href link.

Comment: thanks, i was trying to find a way of directly doing it in HTML but I guess that it's not possible

Comment: yes, i guess there is no other way to do it in html. Please mark answer to make the question resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use This

```
<a href="/order/trackorder?orderId=@Model.OrderCode">@Model.OrderCode</a>
</p>
```

So Your parameter should be string , you can convert it to int or something else.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for it for Razor Pages:

```
<a asp-route-school="@Model.School" asp-page="/school_info">School Profile</a>
```

Comment: thanks .NET teammate